# How to use VTK with C language?

Tags: c, vtk

I've already installed CMake, but I haven't undertood how to use The visualizer Toolkit!I have done a .dat file with C and I want to make a .vtk file.

Comment: vtk files are really easy to write. www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf. What do you which to write ? Structured Grid, Rectilinear Grid or Polygonal Data ? How do you write your .dat ? Tell us more !

Comment: @francis I write my .dat with C(I create a file .dat into the program).I have to write a Structured Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A .vtk structured grid looks like this :

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Really cool data
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_GRID
DIMENSIONS 2 2 1
POINTS 4 float
0 0 0
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
POINT_DATA 4
SCALARS volume_scalars char 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default
1 2 3 4
```

Using the toolkit is not absolutely mandatory to write such a file. You can try to use it if you are working with c++. http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/StructuredGrid/StructuredGrid

Or you can use `fopen()`, `fprintf()` and `fclose()` in `stdio.h`.
Combine things like :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 ...
 FILE* f = fopen("bla.vtk","w");
 if(f==NULL){printf("file vtk, failed to open\n");}
 fprintf(f, "# vtk DataFile Version 2.0");
 ...
 fprintf(f,"%f %f %f\n",x,y,z);
 ...
 fclose(f);
```

Good luck !

Comment: Really thank you! What are the dimensions? And points 4 float? And look_up table?

Comment: `DIMENSIONS` are the dimensions of the grid, here a minimal grid, with a single layer in the z direction, so 2 2 1. `POINTS 4 float` corresponds to the prototype `POINTS n dataType` where `n` is the number of points in the unstructured grid, logically 2x2x1. You will find more about this in http://www.vtk.org/VTK/img/file-formats.pdf